# Changing sql to hql with joins

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

What seems to be wrong with my hql query?

```
String queryString = "SELECT A.INITIAL, A.NUMBER, A.OWNR_SCAC , A.INITIAL||A.NUMBER AS CAR," + 
            "A.LESSEE_SCAC, A.TRUK_CNT, A.EQP_TYP_CD, A.AXL_CNT, B.STABILITY_DEV_EQP," +
            "A.C_CNT, A.G_WGT, B.TRUK_AXL_CNT, A.EIN FROM DS.E_UT AS A" +
            "LEFT JOIN DS.E_PRIMARY AS B" +
            "WHERE A.INITIAL||A.NUMBER IN (:carList) AND A.INITIAL IN {:initList) AND A.NUMBER IN (:numberList)" + 
            "AND B.TRUK_AXL_CNT > 0";
```

ERROR:

org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: A near line 1, column 263

I assume it is talking about the `A` after `FROM DS.E_UT AS A`

Comment: Can you show your hibernate mapping class or file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In HQL you do **not** give the table and column names. Instead you give the Java class names and member variable names (or getter/setter) names of the classes and member variables which you mapped to the tables and columns.

Comment: if a variable is in another class (joined variable)...how do i reference that?

Comment: Use either (for example) `from ClassA inner join ClassB where ClassA.variable = ...` or `from ClassA A inner join ClassB B where A.variable = ...`

Comment: ok now im getting "Invalid path:'null.TRUK_AXL_CNT' when I add the ClassB.variable to the query

Comment: I guess TRUK_AXL_CNT is the database name of the column. You have to use the class member name, sth. like `B.trukAxlCnt > 0`. Please provide the mapping files for these two tables; if not it is only guessing.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add some spaces on each new line.

```
"A.C_CNT, A.G_WGT, B.TRUK_AXL_CNT, A.EIN FROM DS.E_UT AS A" +
"LEFT JOIN DS.E_PRIMARY AS B"
```

Would become:

```
A.C_CNT, A.G_WGT, B.TRUK_AXL_CNT, A.EIN FROM DS.E_UT AS ALEFT JOIN DS.E_PRIMARY AS B
```

Note the 'ALEFT'

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure of your schema or if this is what you are looking for, but you could just map your joined tables together. This could make things a little easier and you wouldnt need to explicitly join in your query.

[Here is a small example](http://tadtech.blogspot.com/2007/02/hibernate-annotation-many-to-oneforeign.html)

A sample query from that example could look something like:

```
SELECT p 
    FROM Person 
WHERE p.name like :name 
AND p.address.street like :street
```

Comment: so if I do this? how would my query be formed?

Comment: You would write your query referencing your objects as they are named in your schema. I added an example based off of the example link.